# SwiftUI Combine Framework shared receiveCompletion code block

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, combine

In a SwiftUI subscriber, you would normally have this

```
authenticate
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // Move to the main thread
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error): ()
        case .finished: ()
        }
    }, receiveValue: { _ in })
```

I would like to extract the receiveCompletion code block to be shared between multiple subscribers expection the same completion i.e the below to be separated and used in multiple subscribers.

```
receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(let error): ()
            case .finished: ()
            }
```

Comment: You can simply make a separate function for 'receiveCompletion' and pass the function everywhere.

Comment: @andykkt, i don't seem to be doing it correctly. Yet to wrap my hands properly around closures. Please help

Comment: A (possibly interesting) sidenote: If the type of the error is `Never`, you can omit the `receiveCompletion` part (in case you're only interested in receiving new values). You can achieve this by mapping the error to some value (possibly `nil`)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write simple functions that encapsulate the logic:

```
extension Publisher where Failure == Never {

    public func sinkOnMain(
        receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {

        receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: receiveValue)
    }
}

extension Publisher {

    public func sinkOnMain(
        receiveCompletion: @escaping ((Subscribers.Completion<Self.Failure>) -> Void),
        receiveValue: @escaping ((Self.Output) -> Void)) -> AnyCancellable {

        receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: receiveCompletion, receiveValue: receiveValue)
    }
}
```

They both do the same work as regular `sink` but first the move the execution to the main run loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i was looking for

```
static func handleCompletion(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Error>) {
        switch completion {
        case .failure(let error): ()
        case .finished: ()
        }
    }
```

Then call it like this

```
authenticate
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) // Move to the main thread
    .sink(receiveCompletion: handleCompletion
    , receiveValue: { _ in })
```